# How to pass text to 3rd party app in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app generates some sort of text information.

User presses button like "Share" in my app and after that pops up a windows with a list of installed applications or only apps which can recieve string parameter. After that, user selects, for example, "Mail" app and then it is opened with the new email message and with a given text from my app. Or user selects Skype app and then it is opened with a given text.

How could those scenarios be implemented in iOS?

PS: I already saw similar behavior in Android app (via `Intent` extras).

UPDATE: I posted the answer below that works for me (via UIActivityViewController) exactly how I need.

Comment: there is no generic way if doing this in iOS

Comment: Look at `UIActivityViewController`.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy. It work for me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best solution for me is

```
- (IBAction)onShare:(id)sender {
    NSString *textStr = self.textToShare.text;
    NSArray *items = @[textStr];

    UIActivityViewController *activity = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                          initWithActivityItems:items
                                          applicationActivities:nil];

    [self presentViewController:activity animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

It does exactly what I need. It shows popup view with the list of apps which are able to receive text string. Then user can select any of them and controller sends text to it.

Comment: Not sure how this solves the problem that you where asking us, how does this pass text between apps the user has selected? Surely the passing the text between apps realize on whether the developer of the app you are passing too has set up a `URL Scheme` that accepts the text as a parameter? Also why  not pass `self.textToShare.text` straight into `initWithActivityItems` like `initWithActivityItems:@[self.textToShare.text]` means you can reduce your code by two lines and is still readable.

Comment: Why do you think it does not solve my problem? It seems that it opens a view with appropriate list of apps which could receive text strings. And user is able to select the app and then it pass the given text to the selected app. Or do you think it works different?

Comment: Also I am agree, that the code could be slightly reduced in a way you has noted. But I am not sure that code with extra [] could be more readable.

Comment: To be honest I think you haven't asked your question in the way that you want it. So just adding more detail might be the best option here saying how it resolves your issue

Answer (score 2):

There is no single answer that will work for all target apps. You need to research each app and see if it has a facility for receiving info from other apps.

A simple way to do this is to invoke an URL that targets the other app.

For mail, you could invoke a `mailto://` URL that composes an email with the text in the desired field(s) (to, cc, bcc, subject, or body.)

If the app supports the iOS document model you may be able to pass it a document to open.

If the target app has a server then you may also be able to connect to the server and send data to it that way. Again, this is not a question you can ask in general. The answer will be different for each target app, and for some apps the answer will be "you can't, because it doesn't have any mechanism to receive data from an outside app."

Android is a different beast with different abilities than iOS. iOS is more of a "walled garden", with very limited access outside of your app.

Comment: Using `UIActivityViewController` would be the best answer.

Comment: But would only work if the receiving app had built-in support for that. It gets back to my statement that the answer is different for each app to which you want to send data.

Comment: Right. But look at the question - press a "share" button. Window pops up with list of apps. User picks one such as "Mail". That is the exact description of `UIActivityViewController`.

Comment: Thanks Duncan, but in my particular case it seems that UIActivityViewController works very well.