# Paste text into text box of another 3rd party application on Mac OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, accessibility-api

I am building a cocoa application on Mac. Is it possible to 
1) Bring 3rd party application window to focus.
2) Position the cursor into the text box of 3rd party application window? 
3) Insert text into the text box.

Edit:- I tried to achieve this using AXUIElementSetAttributeValue but I am unable to make it work. 
Getting the corresponding AXUIElement works but after setting the text, changes are not visible in text box.
I tried using the accessibility inspector to grab the  details of the control. The control is of type "AXWebArea".
Here is the code.

```
    NSString *newTextStr = @"Hi!";

    AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(windRef, kAXFocusedAttribute, kCFBooleanTrue);

    AXError status = AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(windRef, kAXValueAttribute, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(newTextStr));

    if (status != kAXErrorSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"AXUIElementSetAttributeValue failed");
    }
    AXUIElementPerformAction(windRef, kAXConfirmAction);
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: You can see https://kotikan.com/blog/item/passing-data-between-ios-apps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass text to 3rd party app in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27861946/how-to-pass-text-to-3rd-party-app-in-ios)

Comment: The best way to do this is with Applescript or Javascript. Javascript support his much newer. Look here ;  https://github.com/dtinth/JXA-Cookbook/wiki

Comment: You might be able to do this with the Accessibility API but your app needs permission from the user. Search for `AXUIElementSetAttributeValue`.